# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for exportLink

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a basic javascript snippet to download a **publically shared file** from google drive. I created an API key and configured my domain to be on the list of allowed referrers. I get the typical CORS error when trying to open the exportLink as described here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads. The download link works just fine when accessed in the browser.

**Error:**

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Code:**

```
// setup api key
gapi.client.setApiKey('myKey');

// load libraries and get file from drive API
...

// download file 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', file['exportLinks']['text/csv']);
xhr.onload = function() {
    callback(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    callback(null);
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed that this is a bug in the Drive API, but it is only affecting the exportLinks for New Google Sheets file. Old Google Sheets and other Google file types should work correctly. I've raised it with the team, but it's unclear how long it will take to fix. Unfortunately there are no simple workarounds, and the only solution would be to introduce a server-side component that would download the file and then pass it along to the client.

Comment: You can follow the status of the issue here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3737

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a solution, but you can try using [the PyDrive library](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html). It's developed by the Google Drive team. This library works pretty nicely and I was able to download a csv file with just the following lines:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'YOUR ID HERE'})
file.GetContentFile('test.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
```

Make sure to put your client_secrets.json in the same directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10430772)

Comment: @Andy Aren't you going a bit too far? I mentioned that its not a solution, but if the issue was blocking his work then what I suggested works.

Comment: It's the first part of your answer that gave me trouble. "This isn't a solution" means your answer practically begs for a flag. If you change the answer to an answer with more context / reasoning, I'll happily remove the flag.