# CORS on exportLinks for Google Docs spreadsheets not working

Tags: google-drive-api, cors

As per [spec](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads), Google Docs can be downloaded in different formats using the appropriate `exportLinks` entry in the file metadata obtained using the Drive API. The URLs specified by these entries support CORS, so one can use them from pure Javascript, without a proxy.

This works for most files and document types (doc, presentation) but not spreadsheets. When you try an XHR GET on a spreadsheet `exportLinks` URL from browser Javascript,

1. The OPTIONS request returns a valid response, but it has an Expires header of `Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT`
2. The browser gives up at this point (probably due to the Expires)
3. Doing a GET with the same Authorization, Referer, Origin headers using `curl` returns the spreadsheet alright, but the response headers don't contain any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so it wouldn't have worked from the browser.

Other document types behave in the expected manner for OPTIONS and GET, returning correct Expires and CORS headers.

In fact, old spreadsheets - those with exportLink URLs which look like `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=XXX&exportFormat=xlsx` also work. The problem is confined to new sheets, whose exportLink URLs look like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=XXX&exportFormat=xlsx`.

I hit this issue with [pigshell](http://pigshell.com) using the following steps:

1. Visit [pigshell](http://pigshell.com) using a desktop browser (Chrome/Firefox/Safari)
2. Attach a Google account by clicking on the Google icon in the rightbar
3. In the pigshell CLI,

   ```
   cd /gdrive/<username@gmail.com>
   ls
   gcat <docfilename>                # Displays PDF version of doc
   gcat <spreadsheetfilename>        # CORS failure, examine browser console/devtools
   gcat <spreadsheetcreatedyearsago> # Works
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same question that was asked here:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for exportLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823456/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-for-exportlink)

It seems to be a known bug when using the Drive API with the new version of Google Sheets (other Google file types and the older version of sheets don't seem to have the issue). Unfortunately, no known workarounds, except "to introduce a server-side component that would download the file and then pass it along to the client."

Comment: Thanks. Somehow missed that question. It's a shame that a simple straight-line failure has not been fixed in months, and what's more, doesn't even appear in the list of open issues.

Comment: hey @ryanroth, do you know, has this issue been solved?